# How to get an element using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get the reference of the corresponding hello when the checkbox is clicked. Please help me to guide what to do

[image]

[image]

I have tried this that when the checkbox is change then the pass function will be called. But dont know how to get the reference of hello so that i can apply styling if the checkbox is changed.

Comment: Avoid posting images of code. copy and paste it right into the post editor.

Comment: If you want to get the target of the click event, reference `event.target` using the `event` param of the event handler's callback.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass either `event` or `this` to the inline `onchange="pass()"` handler.

```js
function pass(event) {
  const parent = event.target.parentElement;
  const p = parent.querySelector('p');
  p.dataset.active = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    p.dataset.active = false;
  }, 500)
}
```

```css
p[data-active="true"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(event)" />
      <p>Hellow</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(event)" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(event)" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
function pass(checkbox, event) {
  const parent = checkbox.parentElement;
  const p = parent.querySelector('p');
  p.dataset.active = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    p.dataset.active = false;
  }, 500)
}
```

```css
p[data-active="true"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(this, event)" />
      <p>Hellow</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(this, event)" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" onchange="pass(this, event)" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example of a global event listener:

```js
function pass(checkbox, event) {
  const parent = checkbox.parentElement;
  const p = parent.querySelector('p');
  p.dataset.active = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    p.dataset.active = false;
  }, 500)
}

document.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('ch')) {
    pass(event.target, event);
  }
});
```

```css
p[data-active="true"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <input class="ch" type="checkbox" />
      <p>Hellow</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="ch" type="checkbox" />
    <p>Hellow</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function eventHandler(event) {
   const target = event.target.closest('input');

   if (target === null) {
     return;
   }

   const p = target.closest('li').querySelector('p');
   // Here is your element <p>
}

const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

ul.addEventListener('click', eventHandler);
```

Then remove an inline event `onchange="pass(event)"` and use one event handler that handles event delegation.

Comment: Whoever voted down should provide the reason. This would help to understand why.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using plain html and javascript you can achieve this by giving the the element an id, like this. `<p id="your-element-id">Hello</p>`

And, in the function that you are passing to the `input: check` field, you can access that element by it's id.

Like this :

```js
function pass() {
  // your own code here

  //then, Get a reference to the element with the specified ID
  var element = document.getElementById("your-element-id");

  // Now you can manipulate the 'element' object
  element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  element.innerHTML = "New content";
  // ... and whatever else you want to change you can do that
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the post - how to find the element clicked if multiple elements call `pass`?

Comment: @traktor if you want to check which checkbox was clicked that triggered the pass function you can get the `event.target.id` and add ids to the checkbox input fields.